# Why the property Range not exist in Random class in unity?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class Multiple_objects : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject prefab;
    public GameObject[] gos;
    public int NumberOfObjects;
    private ThirdPersonCharacter[] thirdPersonCharacter;
    private Animator[] _animator;
    private int count = 0;

    void Awake()
    {
        Vector3 v3 = prefab.transform.position;
        _animator = new Animator[NumberOfObjects];
            gos = new GameObject[NumberOfObjects];
        for(int i = 0; i < gos.Length; i++)
        {
            count = count + 2;
            GameObject clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
            gos [i] = clone;
            gos [i].transform.position = new Vector3 (v3.x - count, v3.y, v3.z);
            _animator [i] = gos[i].GetComponent<Animator> ();
            Math.Round(Random
```

When i type point after the Random like: Random.
I have only Equals and ReferenceEquals

And if i create a variable of Random for example:

```
Random _random;
```

Then i type _random.
I get more propeties but not Range.

Comment: Just a shameless plug of my [RandomGenerator](https://github.com/chanibal/RandomGenerator) utility, it solves your problem of having an instanceable `Random` class and provides better control over randomness of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using both the UnityEngine and System namespace. Both of these namespaces contain a **Random** class, so Visual Studio/Unity doesn't know which one you want to use. To specify which random you want to use, you would simply do this:

```
UnityEngine.Random.Range(0.0f, 5.0f);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why the property Range not exist in Random class in unity?
>
> Random _random;
>   _random.Rand...

`Range` is a `static` function in the `Random` class. You don't need to create instance of the class to use static functions inside then. You call static functions directly.

This should do it: `Random.Range(0f,3f);`

If you are getting the `Random' is an ambiguous reference between`System.Random' and `UnityEngine.Random' error then that's because you have`using System;`(which you did in your code) and therefore you **must** use the **full** namespace to access Unity random function.

```
UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 3f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Write UnityEngine.Random.Range

You have to clarify the namespace.

Unless you want the .net Random ( in that case look at the other answer)